# Excel VBA Skip Do while loop

Tags: excel, vba

How to use continue statement to skip the loop for next iteration. So that if condition fails the loop must go for next iteration

The code goes as follows:

```
Do While i<50 
    If IsEmpty(Cells(EndRow, 25)) = False Then
        Continue Do 
    Else 
        Cells(EndRow, 25).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 
    i = i+1 
LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're after this

```
Do While i < 50
    If IsEmpty(Cells(EndRow, 25)) Then Cells(EndRow, 25).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    i = i + 1
Loop
```